# Регистрация фоновой задачи в UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, background-task

На данный момент я хочу зарегистрировать фоновую задачу. Вот код регистрации:

```
    private void RegisterBackgroundTask()
    {
        var exampleTaskName = "BackgroundTaskForMedia";
        foreach (var task in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks)
        {
            if (task.Value.Name == exampleTaskName)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Unregister");
                task.Value.Unregister(true);
                break;
            }
        }
        BackgroundTaskBuilder taskBuilder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
        taskBuilder.Name = taskName;
        taskBuilder.TaskEntryPoint = taskEntryPoint;
        taskBuilder.SetTrigger(new TimeTrigger(15,false));
        var registration = taskBuilder.Register();
    }
```

И вот код этой фоновой задачи (чисто пример, что бы просто понять, работает это или нет):

```
    public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        _deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
        Debug.WriteLine("In BackgroundTaskForMedia.Run");
        await Open();
        _deferral.Complete();

    }
    private async Task Open()
    {
        await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(_uri);
    }
```

Так вот, при запуске приложения эта таска кажется регистрируется, поскольку после нового вызова кода регистрации на консоль выводится сообщение об отмене регистрации.

Однако сама задача не выполняется. Новая страница в браузере не открывается, на Debug панели ничего нового. Что не так?

Answer (score 1):

Заработало когда поменял это:

```
taskBuilder.SetTrigger(new TimeTrigger(15,false));
```

На это:

```
taskBuilder.SetTrigger(new SystemTrigger(SystemTriggerType.NetworkStateChange, false));
```

Пхах, оказывается и раньше все работало. Сегодня включил комп и мне вывело извещение о работе таски(а я приложение не включал). Теперь только нужно как то снять все эти таски.